# Maven + Modules + Eclipse: Running different Applications in Eclipse using 'Run As'

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, swing, module

I am currently fighting with Eclipse and this pain inducing module mechanism introduced in Java 9 while also using Maven. I am utilizing Java 17 while developing a small Kafka event consuming application piping events to disk while also analyzing and maintaining the received events. I now want to simply run a (smaller) Swing Application to visualize the data and try several different ways of processing the data. Finally I plan to port the UI part to Flutter as Java UI is a sad affair... .

Anyway, before I throw more hours at this problem, I would like to know if there is something simple that I can do.

Currently I try to have multiple application in the project that I still can run using 'Run As' in Eclipse. Deleting the old launch configurations helped with ClassNotFoundException(s) that I got right when introducing modules.

Now I run into the error messages:
`Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module org.slf4j not found`

I understand that I have to provide the module-path along with --add-modules in the VM-Arguments section but it does not work, since using --add-modules with multiple modules (comma separated), the app launch fails by trying to interpret the second module added as the class to load. (`Error: Could not find or load main class org.slf4j Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j`)

I also learned that there is a Main class to be created and set as the module's main class but that would not allow for using multiple application of the same project to be run using 'Run As'.

Questions:

1. Can I run a AWT+Swing application (or even SWT?) without using modules except for downgrading to Java 1.8?
2. Can I fix the module not found issue?
3. Can I switch to Eclipse SWT without dealing with modules? (I doubt that)
4. Should I invest the time to switch to Kotlin? Does that make sense regarding their UI Libraries?

Since I am going to use Flutter when it comes to the client app anyways, I might expose the data using a REST-Server already and go from there but I would first use a Swing application as it should produce quicker insights and simplify development.

As I write this, one additional idea is to separate the UI part in another Maven project that compiles and runs Java 1.8 code, so this should run without Modules as well. Since this might be doable I would still see the Java Modules version working.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: _"I understand that I have to provide the module-path along with --add-modules in the VM-Arguments section..."_ - This is not how it works in Eclipse. Specifying VM arguments should not required at all. In Java 17 you can still use the classpath by not having a `module-info.java` file in the default package. Be aware that Kotlin is not vendor neutral.

Comment: 1. Yes, by deleting `module-info.java` file (the system library consists of modules which cannot be changed) 2. Add the JAR containing the missing module to the modulepath (_Project > Properties: Java Build Path: Libraries_) 3. Yes (see 1.) 4. For what purpose?